# how to make a working delete button on a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongoose, datatable

so  i want to add a button to a DataTable, the button should delete an account from the database, im using, node js, expresjs (whit html engine) and mongoose 
this is my model

```
const Account = new Schema({
  username: String,
  names: {type:String,default:""},
  lastnames: {type:String,default:""},
  password: String,
  email: String,
  phone: String,
  suspended: {type: Boolean, default: false},
  type:  { type: String, enum: TIPOS_USUARIO, default: 'dev' },
  lastlogin: 'moment'
});
```

and this is the script on the html that generates a DataTable and the button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "/adminpanel/webapi/userlist",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "username" },
        { "data": "names" },
        { "data": "lastnames" },
        { "data": "phone" },
        { "data": "email" },
        { "data": "suspended" },
        { "defaultContent": "<button>Delete!</button>"},
    ], 
});

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
    alert( "You are about to delete an user");

    var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    table.row('.selected').remove().draw( true );
     });
});
```

but it generates the button and the alert message, ut it doesnt delete the account from database nor the DataTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.selected` is not added on the table rows anywhere. So change the `table.row('.selected').remove().draw( true );` to get tr just like the data.
`table.row($(this).closest('tr')).remove().draw()`

To update the database, you will need to make ajax call and handle the id of user and query to delete that.

```js
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function() {
  alert("You are about to delete an user");

  var data = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
  
  //Do ajax call to delete from database.
  
  table.row($(this).closest('tr')).remove().draw();
});
```